# Help me with a proof syntax in Probabilities, min() in R.Vs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

> Given U,V independent exponential R.Vs. Find the law of min(U,V).

I understand some of the basics, but I need exact formal proof at the beginning since I've seen very few of these questions. I will write the beginning which I hesitate of. Could you correct my mistakes? Or approve my 100% correctness.

My solution:

U and V are Random Variables. Thus we are looking for

$P\{\{t<U\} \bigcap \{t<V\}\}$

U, V are independent. Hence

$=P\{t<U\}\bigcap P\{t<V\}$

Which is in turn:

$=F_U(t)F_V(t)$

And then we calculate and differentiate.

Did I write it wrong somewhere? Is everything correct?

Comment: It's "almost" correct except the last equality. Note that the cumulative distribution function $F_U(t)$ is defined as the probability that $U\le t,$ not the other way round. That means, $P(U>t)=1-F_{U}(t).$

Comment: One more comment: $\{t < U\}$ and $\{t < V\}$ are events -- that is, sets -- so it's fine to write something like $\{t < U \} \cap \{t < V\}$, as you did. However, $P(t < U)$ is a *number*, so it doesn't make sense to write something like $P(t < U) \cap P(t < V)$ much like how it doesn't make sense to write $3 \cap 8$. Use multiplication there instead.

Comment: Wow. Many thanks! I'm surprised of myself, disapointed though that I had not understood it beforehand. :) Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, many thanks I was making this mistake all the time. Will correct now.

Comment: Hi, sorry similar but no. As I stated I do know the answer, I just didn't know how to write it using my own words. I apologies for the dumb question, but I really had a hard time with these min variables. I needed someone to write it  **using theory of groups** which the answers lack there. Will it help if I edit the title? I changed it I think 10 times while I was writing the question. Edit: I edited the title, let me know if it helps.